# I made an eclipse plugin fragment, testing it works but deploying it doesn't

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I made a plugin fragment for the PMD eclipse plugin, it implements a rule that checks the project's structure. When I test-run it in eclipse the fragment works but when I deploy it it doesn't.

The way I deploy it is simply exporting it as a .jar and adding that to the eclipse/plugin directory. A simple "hello world" fragment works but my slightly more complex plugin doesn't.

Here is the plugin's manifest and build info:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis.pmd.rule
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis.pmd.rule;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Fragment-Host: net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin;bundle-version="4.0.7.v20150522-1709"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis.archnemesis,
 de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis.core.chralx,
 net.sourceforge.pmd,
 org.eclipse.emf.common.util,
 org.junit;version="4.11.0"
```

build.properties:

```
source.. = src/main/java/,\
           src/test/java/,\
           src/test/resources/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .
```

Its strange because the eclipse instance recognizes the plugin as being present but it isn't being added to the host plugin correctly or something.

Comment: You have the fragment marked as `singleton:=true`. Is this because you have a fragment.xml? That also must be included included in your `build.properties` config.

Comment: The fragment doesn't have a fragment.xml. How should I modify the `build.properties`?

Comment: You don't necessarily need one; it's only used when you have static configuration to add to your fragment. What is in your fragment that should be incorporated into the PMD plug-in, and how does it get registered?

Comment: Its just a custom rule implementation, so the class extends an `abstractJavaRule` and implements a few methods. When it gets added to the host plugin you simply add the class to the existing set of rules. So the class needs to be logically added to the plugin but doesn't need an extension point.

Comment: Start Eclipse with the '-clean' option to get it to rebuild the plugin cache.

Comment: Turns out that one of the plugin's dependencies is causing it to malfunction, I have no idea why but it seems that the dependencies are causing issues.